# I have an excel file. In which there are multiple columns and rows how does one filter the columns by the rows for ggplot

Tags: r, excel

I have an excel file that has data as such:

[image: Image of xslx]

I have to create a box plot and am using ggplot. How does one filter it such that the results for `Lead` will show based on what the `Ward` number is. For example if I say `Ward==1` then it will show the results `Lead` 5.0, 7.8 and 6.3 and create a box plot with these . I am trying to create a `geom_boxplot` and `stat_boxplot`.

Comment: Can you try `ggplot(df1, aes(y = Lead, group = Ward)) + geom_boxplot()`

Comment: @akrun you are a savior. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can specify the `group` as 'Ward' and apply the `geom_boxplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(Ward = factor(Ward)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Ward, y = Lead, fill = Ward)) +
       geom_boxplot()
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Ward = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), Lead = c(5, 
7.8, 3.6, 2.8, 6.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could subset your data then make your boxplot.

```
test <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5),Ward=c(1,1,2,3,1),Lead=c(5.0,7.8,3.6,2.8,6.3))
```

The above code just creates sample data

```
  ID Ward Lead
1  1    1  5.0
2  2    1  7.8
3  3    2  3.6
4  4    3  2.8
5  5    1  6.3
```

Subset the data

```
subset(test,test$Ward==1)
```

This yeilds

```
  ID Ward Lead
1  1    1  5.0
2  2    1  7.8
5  5    1  6.3
```